How to properly bundle React + Vite app with external react dependencies
Imagine we are starting a fresh Vite + React app:
npm create vite@latest my-react-app --template react

App is set up with React + JavaScript.
Imagine I want to reduce bundle size and load React from CDN, the most promising and reasonable approach I tried so far is:

Add script loading in index.html, like so:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ( ... )
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router-dom/6.25.1/react-router-dom.production.min.js"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


Remove react & react-dom from dependencies and set as peer dependencies in package.json, like so:
{
  ( ... )
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.25.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.11.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.2",
    "eslint": "^9.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.37.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.12",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.8"
  }
}


Set up Vite building in vite.config.js, like so:
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["react", "react-dom", "react-router-dom"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          react: "React",
          "react-dom": "ReactDOM",
          "react-router-dom": "ReactRouterDOM",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});



When I run npm run dev, the site works as expected.
When I run npm run build, the bundle size is actually reduced, so looks like dependencies are external.
But when I run npm run preview, to check out bundled app, I get such error:
localhost/:1 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I understand that either one of two is happening:

external dependencies didn't load, or
the imports in the app are not remaped to those external
dependencies,

I tried multiple approaches with a bit of random changes in package.json, and vite.config.js, made a lot of iterations.
I also tried using additional plugins, like vite-plugin-externals and also couldn't solve it.

Just a note, if your going to use CDN's,  I would strongly recommend you implement a hash using the integrity attribute.   The polyfill.io that effected thousands of websites, including some big names is an example of what can happen otherwise.
